# Validate array suitable for csv

Tags: php, csv

Is it possible in php to validate an array so that it can be determined early on if the structure is suitable for export to a csv format?

If it is, what would be the best way to do it?

Im thinking of exceptions like the array must be an array of arrays (for each row) i.e.:

```
array(
    array('row1-col1', 'row1-col2')
)
```

also that first child arrays cannot be arrays i.e.

```
array(
    array(array('this is not allowed'), 'row1-col2')
)
```

and there must be many more exceptions to the format for successful import.

I am importing with a simple loop and fputcsv

Comment: There's never a "best way" to do something. There are many ways and each one has it's pros and cons. It all depends on what's important to you. And as for your first question: of course it can be done, just check that the first-child elements (first level) don't have members which are arrays themselves, which can be easily checked by `is_array()` function.

Comment: I am just looking for something that is very stable.  I had wondered whether there was an existing php function that did this

Comment: That did what ? takes and array an generates a CSV file ?

Comment: No, that return true of false if the array structure can be safely converted to csv

Comment: sounds to me like `fputcsv` does exactly that (returns FALSE if it fails).

Comment: yes but if it fails half way through an import then it will have already written several rows.

Comment: so write it to a tmp file and copy it only after you're done. then delete the tmp file and you're good to go.